# How to set Service Reference authorization?

Tags: asp.net, soap, web-config

How do you set the authorization for a Service Reference in web.config?

I'm writing a password retriever, that sends the users password by e-mail. The e-mail is sent via a SOAP service reference. However, each time I try to declare a reference to the SOAP API the web app returns to the login page - the default action when you request something that requires user authorization.

Naturally, I need to be able to call the service reference without the user being logged in, since it's after all a password retriever. I know how this is done for `<location path="Webpage.aspx">` type of stuff, but not for service references, and I'm having a hard time finding the answer on Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ach! Turned out it wasn't an athorization problem in the end - some wizard had poked about in web.config and made a mess, which ended up causing an issue resembling an authorization problem.

Please, vote to close question, as it's no longer relevant.